# How to remove by default clear checkbox in Django

Tags: python, django

[As you can see there is clear checkbox on the page
I don't want to clear the image and keep the default one
But Django is adding this automatically. Is there any way remove it or select it inside code
to apply operations on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSfs6.png)

Comment: plz tell me more about your problem. it's not fully clear. tnx

Comment: Can you see the image? Is it visible ?

Answer (score 0):

May be a bad practice but you can remove the checkbox with jquery.
 I am assuming you have some knowledge of jquery. 
first import the jquery cdn at the end of the template page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then type this remove the checkbox (Note: This will delete all checkboxes)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').remove()
```

or if you are using many checkboxes in page, you can simply remove by adding index of checkbox you want to remove

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')[1].remove()
```

Comment: Hi, So there one question regarding your answer. Do I need to add Script tag in the main template which is used by other templates. And where should I put this: $('input[type="checkbox"]')[1].remove()  ?

Comment: Using in main will create problems in other templates if you are putting checkbox intentionally on them. Use script tag where your form is rendered but make sure to add script tag after that input field or form. So, script will run after input field is rendered to template, otherwise script won't affect anything